# TypeError: A common type cannot be infered from types float, string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, graphlab

I'm able to get the data [from here](http://tech4partner.com.cp-in-5.webhostbox.net/recommend_test.php) in DataFrame. When I'm converting the DataFrame into SFrame using graphlab then this error is showing:

> TypeError: A common type cannot be infered from types float, string.

My Code is

```
import graphlab

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as pt

from numpy import array

from graphlab import SFrame


user_columns =['No','User id','User Name','Skill','Given Test Name','Given Test ID','Recommend Test','Recommend Test ID','Time Start','Time End','Score','Max Score']

data=pd.read_table('http://tech4partner.com.cp-in-5.webhostbox.net/recommend_test.php', sep='^',header=None,names = user_columns)

df2 = data.ix[2:]

df3=df2.reset_index()

df4=df3.drop('index', axis=1)

df5=df4.drop(df4.index[len(df4)-1])

df5=df5.reset_index(1,[len(df5)-1])

df7 = df5.reset_index()

df8=df7.drop('index', axis=1)

df9=df8.head(len(df8))

df9.index = np.arange(1, len(df9) + 1)

df9=df9.head(50)

df9
```

Data is showing in DataFrame at this line..When I convert the DataFrame into Sframe, It gives error.

> **DataFrame converts into SFrame using .Sframe() method**
>
> *t_data = graphlab.SFrame(df9)*
>
> *t_data*

and according to me Data is in well format or may be not. And also I tried two solution but it didn't work for me.

**1)**  I checked every column but no column has different data type.

**2)** I converted every column in a specific data type using

`df.column_name.astype(str)` and df['column_name']= df[coulmn_name].astype(str)

but it didn't work any more.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-c852cd1e7f45> in <module>()
----> 1 t_data = graphlab.SFrame(df9)
      2 t_data
      3 
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\graphlab\data_structures\sframe.pyc in __init__(self, data, format, _proxy)
    951                     pass
    952                 else:
--> 953                     raise ValueError('Unknown input type: ' + format)
    954 
    955         sframe_size = -1
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\graphlab\cython\context.pyc in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
     47             if not self.show_cython_trace:
     48                 # To hide cython trace, we re-raise from here
---> 49                 raise exc_type(exc_value)
     50             else:
     51                 # To show the full trace, we do nothing and let exception propagate
**TypeError: A common type cannot be infered from types float, string.**
```

How can I convert this DataFrame into SFrame?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, If you got feel i wrote something wrong "Urgent" and "Asap" ,which is not acceptable then Sorry. I don't mind you can downvote my question .

Comment: Let me tell you one thing I'm using Jupyter in Anaconda. I've already made a script in Jupyter where DataFrame is easily converted into SFrame without any troubling.Thanx Halfer

Answer (score 0):

try this syntax for conversion:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype(float)
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype(str)
```

Comment: I also used this syntax .. it's not working for me .. and now i edited my question and share completed code as you can see....